# How to get axios post data request on nodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to send a post request using Axios and I also want to access the data from the server. My code is

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/register/',
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({fname, lname, username, email, pass})
})
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})

// and my backend code is
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const firstname = ''
})
```

Request is send properly and my server also accepts the request. but i do not know how to get the values from my server.

please help me. code is working fine just help me in getting the values on server side code

Answer (score 6):

1. Unlike `fetch`, `axios` does not require you to stringify the body of the post request. You can just post like so:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/register/',
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
    body: {fname, lname, username, email, pass}
})
...
```

2. Assuming you are posting to the correct endpoint (e.g. `/register`), on the server side, you would access it this way:

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const fname = req.body.fname;
    ...
})
```

Note that this assumes your backend is properly configured. If all you're running is the code you showed, it won't work as you would need stuff like:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
...
...
app.listen(YOURPORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening to requests on port YOURPORT...`);
});
```

Comment: i tried your code 

req.body.fname

but i am getting undefined

and i also removed json.Stringify()

and
endpoint is correct

Comment: @ShanuRaj Your backend app is not properly configured. Check out the last paragraph of my answer.